# Count number of unique combinations of values within a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have 72x7 double called **P** like this:

```
1 45 2  61 7 1 11  
1 32 6  23 64 1 32  
2 55 32 25 90 3 24  
2 45 6  6 16 3 1  
2 45 4  17 20 3 1  
...
3 87 24 43 71 3 41  
5 64 8  66 75 98 1
```

Two columns I'm interested in are **1** and **6**. Let's call a value in column 1 **m** and a value in column 6 **n**. **m** ranges from 1-6 and **n** ranges from 1 to either 3 or 4. I would like to count how many rows that has a specific combination of **m** and **n**. Let's call this value **x**. For instance, in this example if **m=1** and **n=1**, **x** would be 2 since there are two rows where **m=1** AND **n=1** (row 1 and 2). If **m=2** AND **n=3**, **x** would be 3 (row 3, 4, and 5). 
I intend to do a loop, something like this:

```
for m=1:6
   for n=1:a % a could be either 3 or 4
   x = (operation done here)
   end
end
```

I tried both numel and unique functions but neither gave me the right answer. Could someone help me?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach -

```
%// Get columns 1 and 6 from input matrix, P
P16 = P(:,[1 6])

%// Get unique row combinations and their IDs
[unqrows,~,idx] = unique(P16,'rows')

%// Get the counts for each combination
counts = accumarray(idx(:),1) %// Or histc(idx,1:max(idx))

%// Present the output
out = [unqrows counts]
```

Thus, with P as -

```
P = [1 45 2  61 7 1 11
    1 32 6  23 64 1 32
    2 55 32 25 90 3 24
    2 45 6  6 16 3 1
    2 45 4  17 20 3 1 ]
```

we would have the output as -

```
out =
     1     1     2
     2     3     3
```

So, in the output, the first column represents `m`, the second one would be `n` and the final column would be the expected counts.

Comment: I was about to write a solution.... and this is pretty much what I would have done. Bah lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng I am sorry, as it turns out `accumarray` is fun too! :)

Comment: It's one of my favourite functions to use in MATLAB!  Some of my favourite answers use it :)

Comment: Nice! As usual, there's a similar approach based on `sparse` and `find` (instead of `accumarray` and `unique`)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming *positive integer* values, this uses [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to produce the desired result. The output format is as in [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567560/2586922):

```
[ii, jj, kk] = find(sparse(P(:,1), P(:,6), 1));
result = [ii jj kk];
```

Comment: Nice! Interesting, we are seeing lots of these kinds recently on SO.

Comment: @Divakar Certainly! I had a _deja vu_ feeling while answering this :-)